# How to read items in a JSON Array in react js using filter?

Tags: json, reactjs, filter

I have the following json. From the below json I wanted only the PartNumber of each item in the form of an array. Can anyone please help how to do so using filter?

Below is my code. In the console log am getting only the PartNumber of first item

```
    state = {
        data: MYResult.Products || [],
        partNumbers: []
    };

   componentDidMount(){
      const allPartNumbers = this.state.data.filter(partnumbers =>  
      this.state.data.PartNumber);
      console.log(allPartNumbers)
   }

"Products": [
            {
            "PartNumber": "ALM-GN001",
            "ProductName": "GNSS Filter-LNA Front-End Module",
            "productline": "GPS/GNSS Wireless Amplifiers",
            "AV_47_Frequency_GHz": "1.575",
            "AV_47_NF": ""
            },
            {
            "PartNumber": "ALM-GP001",
            "ProductName": "GPS Filter-LNA-Filter Front-End Module",
            "productline": "GPS/GNSS Wireless Amplifiers",
            "AV_47_Frequency_GHz":"1.565 - 1.606",
            "AV_47_NF": ""
            },
            { 
            "PartNumber": "ALM-GA001",
            "ProductName": "High-Gain, Low-Current LNA with Variable Current and Shutdown Function",
            "productline": "GPS/GNSS Wireless Amplifiers",
            "AV_47_Frequency_GHz": "1.606",
            "AV_47_NF": "0.97"
            },
            {
            "PartNumber": "ALM-GN002",
            "ProductName": "GNSS LNA-Filter Front-End Module with Optional Differential Outputs",
            "productline": "GPS/GNSS Wireless Amplifiers",
            "AV_47_Frequency_GHz": "1.565",
            "AV_47_NF": "0.97"
            }
        ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filter` will create a new array with all the elements that returned a truthy value from the function. You want to use `map` instead and just pluck out the `PartNumber` property.

**Example**

```js
const products = [
  {
    PartNumber: "ALM-GN001",
    ProductName: "GNSS Filter-LNA Front-End Module",
    productline: "GPS/GNSS Wireless Amplifiers",
    AV_47_Frequency_GHz: "1.575",
    AV_47_NF: ""
  },
  {
    PartNumber: "ALM-GP001",
    ProductName: "GPS Filter-LNA-Filter Front-End Module",
    productline: "GPS/GNSS Wireless Amplifiers",
    AV_47_Frequency_GHz: "1.565 - 1.606",
    AV_47_NF: ""
  },
  {
    PartNumber: "ALM-GA001",
    ProductName:
      "High-Gain, Low-Current LNA with Variable Current and Shutdown Function",
    productline: "GPS/GNSS Wireless Amplifiers",
    AV_47_Frequency_GHz: "1.606",
    AV_47_NF: "0.97"
  },
  {
    PartNumber: "ALM-GN002",
    ProductName:
      "GNSS LNA-Filter Front-End Module with Optional Differential Outputs",
    productline: "GPS/GNSS Wireless Amplifiers",
    AV_47_Frequency_GHz: "1.565",
    AV_47_NF: "0.97"
  }
];

const result = products.map(product => product.PartNumber);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a filter operation. Just use `map` instead of `filter`. (replace filter with map)

Answer (score 0):

`Array.filter()` is used to create a new array with the element/s that satisfy the condition giving in the callback function on the `filter(() => condition)` method.

You may use reduce as follows:

```
const productsNumbers = products.reduce((accum, product) => {
  accum.push(product.PartNumber);
  return accum;
}, []);
```

In this case, `productsNumbers[]` would have what's like:
`productsNumbers = []